# What does the microphone in the earpiece of an iPhone do?

Tags: iphone, microphone

I found out that my iPhone 11 has 3 microphones.  As far as I know it's the bottom mic that is used for almost all input.  And the rear next to the camera for camera shots only.  But one thing remains, namely what sits in the earpiece.  But what exactly is it used for? Does anybody have an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I found a succinct description on [MacRumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/three-microphones-on-iphone.1821157/post-20387108)

> > I would like to know which microphone is active with which app?
>
> All three, all the time a mic is needed. One becomes the primary mic,
> and the other two are used for noise cancellation.
>
> As for which mic becomes the primary, it's not app-dependent, but
> rather use-case dependent.
>
> In regular phone mode, obviously the bottom mic is the primary, with
> the rear mic used for noise cancellation. But when you switch to
> speakerphone mode, the phone switches between the three mics depending
> on where a clear, loud human voice is speaking relative to the phone,
> and how the phone is oriented. Same is true for when audio recording
> apps are being used.
>
> For video recording, and FaceTime: Primary mic depends on which camera
> is being used. Turning on the front-facing camera makes the
> front-facing mic the primary. Using the rear camera switches it to the
> rear mic.